# Upgraded Apache Server won't start: Syntax error on line 141 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, server, upgrade, apache2

I upgraded a Ubuntu 12 LTS server to Ubuntu 14 LTS and as a result breaks the apache2 set up (such that the subdomain hosted no longer works).

```
Full Error: [so:warn] [pid 3782] AH01574: module security2_module is already loaded, skipping
apache2: Syntax error on line 141 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mod-
security.conf: No matches for the wildcard '*.conf' in '/etc/modsecurity', 
failing (use IncludeOptional if required)
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Pastebin of apache2.conf: https://pastebin.com/bG7PmmqP
Pastebin of mod-security.conf:https://pastebin.com/rNEF04Xx

/etc/modsecurity just has modsecurity.conf-recommended, when I upgrade to Ubuntu 14 it has I think one other file; so I imagine it's trying to find something in there but failing.

I'm not sure what's wrong or what's happening or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error seems that you just need to create some *.conf file into the '/etc/modsecurity' directory. Copying  modsecurity.conf-recommended into  modsecurity.conf might be a safe option.

Read carefully the  modsecurity.conf-recommended file to see if it fits your needs, i'm not using apache since years